# How to dynamically change GridItems in LazyVGrid with MagnificationGesture [Zoom In, Out] in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The idea is to recreate the same photo layout behaviour like in Apple Photo Library when I can zoom in and out with 1, 3 or 5 photos in a row. I'm stack in a half way. For that I use a `MagnificationGesture()` and based on gesture value I update number of `GridItems()` in `LazyVGrid()`.

---

Please let me know how to achieve it. Thanks a lot

Here's code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .purple, .yellow, .green, .blue, .mint, .orange]
    @State private var colums = Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 1)
//    @GestureState var magnifyBy: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var magnifyBy: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var lastMagnifyBy: CGFloat = 1.0
    let minMagnifyBy = 1.0
    let maxMagnifyBy = 5.0
    
    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
//            .updating($magnifyBy) { (currentState, pastState, trans) in
//                pastState = currentState.magnitude
//            }
            .onChanged { state in
                adjustMagnification(from: state)
                print("Current State \(state)")
            }
            .onEnded { state in
                adjustMagnification(from: state)
//                withAnimation(.spring()) {
//                    validateMagnificationLimits()
//                }
                lastMagnifyBy = 1.0

            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: colums) {
                    ForEach(1..<101) { number in
                        colors[number % colors.count]
                            .overlay(Text("\(number)").font(.title2.bold()).foregroundColor(.white))
                            .frame(height: 100)
                    }
                }
                .scaleEffect(magnifyBy)
                .gesture(magnification)
                .navigationTitle(" Grid")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8)) {
                                colums = Array(repeating: .init(), count: colums.count == 5 ? 1 : colums.count % 5 + 2)
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "square.grid.3x3")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func adjustMagnification(from state: MagnificationGesture.Value) {
        let stepCount = Int(min(max(1, state), 5))
//        let delta = state / lastMagnifyBy
//        magnifyBy *= delta
        withAnimation(.linear) {
            colums = Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: stepCount)
        }
        lastMagnifyBy = state
    }
    
    private func getMinMagnificationAllowed() -> CGFloat {
        max(magnifyBy, minMagnifyBy)
    }
    
    private func getMaxMagnificationAllowed() -> CGFloat {
        min(magnifyBy, maxMagnifyBy)
    }
    
    private func validateMagnificationLimits() {
        magnifyBy = getMinMagnificationAllowed()
        magnifyBy = getMaxMagnificationAllowed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. This uses a TrackableScrollView (git link in the code).
I implemented an array of possible zoomStages (cols per row), to make switching between them easier.

Next to dos would be scrolling back to the magnification center, so the same item stays in focus. And maybe an opacity transition in stead of rearranging the Grid. Have fun ;)

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
// https://github.com/maxnatchanon/trackable-scroll-view.git
import SwiftUITrackableScrollView


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .purple, .yellow, .green, .blue, .mint, .orange]
    
    let zoomStages = [1, 3, 5, 9, 15]
    @State private var zoomStageIndex = 0
    var colums: [GridItem] { Array(repeating: GridItem(spacing: 0), count: zoomStages[zoomStageIndex]) }
    
    @State var magnifyBy: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    @State private var scrollViewOffset = CGFloat.zero // SwiftUITrackableScrollView: Content offset available to use
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: false, contentOffset: $scrollViewOffset) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: colums, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<500) { number in
                        colors[number % colors.count]
                            .overlay(
                                Text("\(number)").font(.title2.bold()).foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                            )
                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit) // always squares
                            .id(number)
                    }
                }
                .scaleEffect(magnifyBy, anchor: .top)
                // offset to correct magnify "center" point
                .offset(x: 0, y: (scrollViewOffset + UIScreen.main.bounds.midY) * (1 - magnifyBy) )
                
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8)) {
                                if zoomStageIndex < zoomStages.count-1 {
                                    zoomStageIndex += 1
                                } else {
                                    zoomStageIndex = 0
                                }
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "square.grid.3x3")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .gesture(magnification)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { state in
                magnifyBy = state
            }
            .onEnded { state in
                
                // find predefined zoom(index) that is closest to actual pinch zoom value
                let newZoom = Double(zoomStages[zoomStageIndex]) * 1 / state
                let newZoomIndex = findClosestZoomIndex(value: newZoom)
                //                print("***", zoomStages[zoomStageIndex], state, newZoom, newZoomIndex)
                
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8)) {
                    magnifyBy = 1 // reset scaleEffect
                    zoomStageIndex = newZoomIndex // set new zoom level
                }
            }
    }
    
    func findClosestZoomIndex(value: Double) -> Int {
        let distanceArray = zoomStages.map { abs(Double($0) - value) } // absolute difference between zoom stages and actual pinch zoom
        //        print("dist:", distanceArray)
        return distanceArray.indices.min(by: {distanceArray[$0] < distanceArray[$1]}) ?? 0 // return index of element that is "closest"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Great tip. I might try this too.

Comment: thank you a lot ChrisR for your solution 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mimic the behaviour of the photos app when magnifying/pinching you have to take into account:

1. The current scale
2. The Scale/Zoom factor required to move to the next layout depending on direction

[image: Example from project below]

[Example project (SwiftUI without third-party libraries)](https://github.com/AlexanderMarchant/DynamicGridZoom/tree/main)

Comment: It's cool, but it has two glaring issues, just like the other answer to this question:

1. Its performance, despite only having ~300 elements to render, is not equivalent to the Photos app.  It stutters very badly when you zoom out all the way.

2. The index of the grid is not calculated when the array is re-ordered, meaning once you zoom in or out, let's say on number 100, the list will jump to item 20.  There is no synchronization of the index.

I'm not sure how Apple did it for their Photos app, but I'm thinking they must have directly used Metal API.

Comment: There are certainly performance/visual improvements that can be made as you have mentioned; if you have time to implement those, feel free to PR it! I believe Apple has simply not used SwiftUI for their Photos app or as you mentioned they have access to something we don't.